# A way to copy text on this forum to preserve math symbols?

Tags: support, scripts, posts, script-request

Is there any way to copy html-text containing Mathjax symbols from this forum's threads and paste it into a word processor (I use Libre office Writer) to preserve nicely looking math symbols?

The standard copy-paste gives just plain text. So does paste using Writer's options «Paste as html-text».